# Beautiful Soup - extract all heading, paragraphs subsequently

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I not just want the content of a page but also the formatting associated to each heading in my final document and not just text without highlighting the headings. e.g. formatting all headings bold.

so far I extract just the text of my div conatiner conating all headings and paragraphhs:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


t=soup.find_all('div',class_=['x'])

    df=[]
    for i in t:
        for head in i:
            df.append(i.get_text())
```

what i need now, is that the text is extracted fo the heading an then the following paragraph subsequently, such that I can format the headings. So i would to iterate through all heading, extract heading and afterwards the paragraph text....

Comment: anyone a suggestion?

Comment: I suggest you give the URL of the page you are trying to parse and show what the output should look like for it. We would then be able to help you further.